# Which iPhone models support the Watch 4/SE?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I have just found out about some health features of the Watch 4+/SE which are extremely appealing to me. My understanding is I'd need an iPhone to set up even if I get a cellular modell. I think I have an iPhone 4 somewhere in the parts drawer but I presume it's too old (I mean, it has a 30 pin...) to use it for this purpose. What gen iPhone should I be buying to get the Watch 4/SE set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least an iPhone 6s for watch SE or an iPhone 6 for the watch 4. I'd recommend you get a used, cracked iPhone 7 or 8 for updates.